# Remove elements from a list, while other list doesn't reset

Tags: python, list, element

I'm currently stuck at this problem, so i have this code.

```
     rij1 = rij2
     rij2.clear()
```

All works correct, but in the end of the loop is a problem.
Rij1 also gets cleared because apparently, python remembers rij1 = rij2
Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: This variable names are not optimized for readability i guess ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rij1 = rij2` stores the same reference of `list` at `rij2` to `rij1`. For storing the new copy of list, you should do:

```
rij1 = rij2[:]

# OR
rij1 = list(rij2)
```

Also, you may use [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) to create shallow copy of `list` as:

```
from copy import copy

rij1 = copy(rij2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a *copy* of the list. After `rij1 = rij2`, both variables are names for the same list.

Something like

```
rij1 = rij2[:]
```

will work.